# Excel IF(AND Multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use an IF statement to determine if a program is in violation based on the number of weeks the program is at.

If MIC, MIE, CIE is over 4 weeks, "Violation". IF Field Events is over 6 weeks "Violation". If either are under the 4 and 6 week thresholds then "No Violation"

I thought it would look something like this but I cant make it work and I dont know how to write out the second part with Field Events:

```
IF(OR(A2="MIE", A2="CIE", A2="MIC")AND(F2>4), "Violation", "No Violation"))
```

The above formula is a stab in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you want to achieve. If you want to nest AND and OR functions, you need to do it like this:

```
=IF(AND(F2>4,OR(A2="MIE", A2="CIE", A2="MIC")), "Violation", "No Violation"))
```

Translated: if F2 is greater than 4 and at the same time A2 is either "MIE" or "CIE" or "MIC", then it's a violation.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for I just didn't know it was called nesting AND, OR functions. This gave me enought to work with so that I could also include the Field Event condition as well.

My final solution:
=IF(AND(F2>4,OR(A2="MIE",A2="CIE",A2="MIC",F2>6,OR(A2="Field Events"))),"Violation","No Violation")

Comment: Thanks so much teylyn!